# Windows Portable Device - Notify when a new file is created / copied / deleted

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, wpd

Is it possible to be notified when a file is deleted from / copied to / storage device using (`IPortableDeviceEventCallback`).

So far i've only been notified when the flash drive was disconnected or its name was changed externally by the user.

**Edit**: I'm interested in receiving the `WPD_EVENT_OBJECT_ADDED`event.

```
IPortableDeviceCapabilities::GetSupportedEvents
```

shows that the needed event is supported, but nothing is sent upon new file copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPD_EVENT_OBJECT_ADDED corresponds to MTP event ObjectAdded.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/dn932706

I think that what events are really sent depends on concrete implementation of MTP protocol on concrete portable device.

I beleave that WPD API main purpose is to manage portable devices like a phones and music players, access and methods to work with usb flash drives are only exported as some layer of compatibility, and may not contain all functions.

If you want to receive such notifications not from portable devices implements MTP, but only from USB flash drives, you should take a look for example on filesystem minifilters
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/ifs/file-system-minifilter-drivers

They could give you needed callbacks.

Comment: As my "Edit" Snippet states, the flash driver does support the Object_Added event. so how come it never sends it?

Comment: As far as "supporting" means here only some layer of abstraction, I think it depends on how are you testing it.

I have tried such case on MS WPD API sample with my flash disk, and it seems that WPD events are fired only when you working with it's content with WPD methods: transfering content through IPortableDevice methods, and so on.

But there are no events from operations with that flash as usb storage device, such as creating folder from Explorer, etc.